# DataSourcePool or @Reference DataSource in WorkflowProcess

Tags: osgi, aem, datasource, osgi-bundle, aem-6

I am writing an AEM Custom Workflow component using the AEM Archetype.  All is good.

I can write code that uses a Reference annotation
@Reference(target = "(&(objectclass=javax.sql.DataSource)(datasource.name=MYDB))")
private DataSource ds;

This works well - I can query, get rows, etc.

However, I do not want to hard code MYDB.

The documentation leads me to believe I can merely add:
@Reference
DataSourcePool dsp;

Then, look up the DataSource however, this does not produce any results.  I can iterate over all datasource names and there are none.
Is it is permissions thing?

My component code looks like this:

public class queryForData implements WorkflowProcess {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(queryForSingleRow.class);

```
@Reference(target = "(&(objectclass=javax.sql.DataSource)(datasource.name=MYDB))")
private DataSource ds;

@Override
public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
```

blah, blah, blah

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I added a Day Commons JDBC Pool connection configuration in configManager.  What I was missing was the DataSource name which is at the bottom of the dialog so, I missed it.  Once I gave it a "name" the DS was found in the code by merely using a
@Reference
private DataSourcePool dsp;
And looking up the DataSource by name.